# Converting HTML to PDF in Python

Tags: python, html, pyinstaller, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

What is a good method for converting an HTML string file to PDF? I am trying to create a simple tool that creates a PDF report using some user inputs and an HTML template. I want to distribute this tool so that other coworkers can use it.

Right now I am trying to use pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf. The issue is that I can only get this code to work when I specify the path to the wkhtmltopdf.exe file. When I package the code using PyInstaller, other users will not be able to use the program because they do not have the HTML template file or a path to wkhtmltopdf. Any ideas on how to resolve this or are there any alternative python packages/methods that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to package the HTML template in your module and you are using `setuptools` you can include any other files with a couple of changes:

1. Create a file called `MANIFEST.in` in your base directory of the module
2. Add all of the files you want to include like this: `include <path/to/file/in/module>`
3. In `setup.py` add `include_package_data=True` to `setup()`

Making those changes should allow your module to include your template and allow the other modules to convert it to a PDF.

If you are having pathing problems within the module, make sure that you are using absolute paths to reference other files. I would suggest using the builtin `os` module to build a path which works for any user. For example: `os.path.abspath("path/to/my/file")`

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is the correct way forward. Follow up question, do you know how to add system environment variables when packaging a Python module? Would os.environ be able to accomplish this?